# loading google directions widget using ajax + colorbox not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, colorbox

I'm on rails and when I have this in my view, the google directions widget loads.

```
<div>
  <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=&amp;up_myLocations=<%= @meeting.location.address %>&amp;up_defaultDirectionsType=&amp;up_autoExpand=&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;lang=en&amp;country=US&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

But if I have a link on my page, say called "directions" and want the above to load in a colorbox when someone clicks directions, the widget does not load.

```
$(".location-directions").click(function(){
  $(this).colorbox({
        open: true,
        href: "/directions?mid=<%= @meeting.id %>",
        width: "400px",
        height: "300px",
        overlayClose:true,
        escKey:true,
        returnFocus:true
    });
    return false;
})
```

The color box that opens is empty. There's no widget. The "/directions" route opens a view which has the same google script path again:

```
<div>
  <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=&amp;up_myLocations=<%= @meeting.location.address %>&amp;up_defaultDirectionsType=&amp;up_autoExpand=&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;lang=en&amp;country=US&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after i've spent the last 5 hours trying different things i finally figured out that i should put "http:" in front of the //www="...
So it should be like "http://www.gmodules.com...etc" 
Hope this helps a bit,off to sleep.

Comment: Hey blast250, thanks for helping out. I actually did try adding in the http but still no luck. I'm working on something else at the moment but will need to revisit this later.